# Is there a term for names with the "X the Y" construction?

Tags: terminology, names, onomastics

For example, "Ivan the Terrible" or "Conan the Barbarian".

Comment: [Epithet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithet)

Comment: As Otavio says, these are examples of *epithets*, but they do not include the most [archetypical class of epithets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithets_in_Homer), like "rosy-fingered dawn" and "swift-footed Achilles". Your examples are also *[appositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition)*.

Comment: Does not seem off topic to me...

Comment: @Ugo: *Epithets* are not part of linguistics, but *appositions* are so it could be on topic for that reason ...

Comment: Lots of languages have appositives.  That's why I think that this question is on-topic.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly valid question on linguistic terminology.

Comment: I second that, German has a similar construct which can be analyzed as an "Adpositional Adjectival Noun": Friedrich der Große/Frederick the Great http://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/AdjectivalNouns/AdjectivalNouns.html

Answer (score 2):

The grammatical construction in the examples is called [apposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition). Note that the definite article "the" is not a necessary part of an apposition, an example without article is *Mary, Peter's sister,*. In languages with case marking, the appositive often agrees in case with the head known, in German *Friedrich der Große* is declined as

> Friedrich der Große, Friedrich des Großen, Friedrich dem Großen,Friedrich den Großen (Nom., Gen., Dat., Acc.)

Answer (score 2):

These "titles" are called [epithets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithet) as already brought up in comments.

As for what this structure might be called *grammatically*, German employs a near identical structure which can be analyzed as an [Adpositional Adjectival Noun](http://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Edeutsch/Grammatik/AdjectivalNouns/AdjectivalNouns.html).

This is just a fancy way of saying that we have a *noun-like* adjective after the name:

> Friedrich der Große / Frederick the Great

Despite the apparent *nounification* (indicated by the Große with a capital G), this adjective is still declined as if it were *der große Mann / the big man*.

Well why reverse the order of the adjective and noun at all? You could maybe compare it to how "A sky blue" sounds a lot more poetic, emphasizing the quality of *being blue*, rather than "A blue sky".

I'd like to believe we can analyze epithets in English identically.

> Ivan the **Terrible**

isn't all too different from

> The Big **Lebowski**

For anyone who has seen the movie there's also The Dude **Lebowski**, so this second naming convention is employed to distinguish between the two Lebowski's. Whereas when we say *Ivan the Terrible* we mean, *Ivan, the Terrible (Tsar, someone you shouldn't be messing with)*.

Whether to treat the Y as more of an adjective or more of a noun is up to you, but I hope this clarified things a bit.